# Trying to understand number of ParseError in html5lib-test

Tags: html, testing, specifications

I was looking at following test case in [html5lib-tests](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-tests):

```
{"description":"<!DOCTYPE\\u0008",
"input":"<!DOCTYPE\u0008",
"output":["ParseError", "ParseError", "ParseError", 
           ["DOCTYPE",  "\u0008", null, null, false]]},
```

[source](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-tests/blob/e633ddfeb0180f71238763576b1f5fdd26a7038f/tokenizer/test3.test#L923)

```
State                      |Input char |  Actions
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Data State                 |  "<"      | -> TagOpenState
TagOpenState               | "!"       | -> MarkupDeclarationOpenState
MarkupDeclarationOpenState | "DOCTYPE" | -> DOCTYPE state
DOCTYPE state              | "\u0008"  | Parse error; -> before DOCTYPE name state (reconsume)
before DOCTYPE name state  | "\u0008"  | DOCTYPE(name = "\u0008"); -> DOCTYPE name state
DOCTYPE name state         | EOF       | Parse error. Set force quirks on. Emit DOCTYPE -> Data state. 
Data state                 | EOF       | Emit EOF.
```

I'm wondering where do those three errors come from? I can only track two, but I assume I'm making an error in logic, somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you're missing is the one from the "Preprocessing the input stream" section:

> Any occurrences of any characters in the ranges U+0001 to U+0008, U+000E to U+001F, U+007F to U+009F, U+FDD0 to U+FDEF, and characters U+000B, U+FFFE, U+FFFF, U+1FFFE, U+1FFFF, U+2FFFE, U+2FFFF, U+3FFFE, U+3FFFF, U+4FFFE, U+4FFFF, U+5FFFE, U+5FFFF, U+6FFFE, U+6FFFF, U+7FFFE, U+7FFFF, U+8FFFE, U+8FFFF, U+9FFFE, U+9FFFF, U+AFFFE, U+AFFFF, U+BFFFE, U+BFFFF, U+CFFFE, U+CFFFF, U+DFFFE, U+DFFFF, U+EFFFE, U+EFFFF, U+FFFFE, U+FFFFF, U+10FFFE, and U+10FFFF are parse errors. These are all control characters or permanently undefined Unicode characters (noncharacters).

This causes a parse error prior to the U+0008 character ever reaching the tokenizer. Given the tokenizer is defined as reading from the input stream, the tokenizer tests assume the input stream has its normal preprocessing applied to it.